# Why do we need JWT tokens for security despite still able to change own`s

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, jwt

I've been searching how to make a public http request secure and all the answers are to use a token like JWT.

But from what I understand, the reason for using this token. Isn't this to prevent someone from trying to modify someone else's data other than your own?

Then user can still manipulate his own data using his own tokens. Because when you first connect to the app, you will get a token from the server.

That person can modify his or her data at any time. Wouldn't he be able to modify the game points he has at any time? (I actually saw an answer in another answer (which said to make that http call only available once after the game is over))

but if he knows the jwt token and http request url then he still can modify right??

Are JWT tokens used in the worst case to keep someone else's data from being touched?

---

More explanation is here.

If I want to change the nickname of StackOverFlow, then the Stackoverflow server will check whether the token in the header I sent and the token stored in the database match.

But suddenly I want to raise my stack overflow score. Then just checking the token is not enough for server I guess. right? How do you prevent in this case?

I don't know what the POST URL that raises the stack overflow point score is, but if a hacker knows the POST URL that raises the score of a user on Stack Overflow, and knows the token, is it manipulative enough?